macOS App with Dial Pad for One-Off Cellular Calls Using iPhone Continuity
Looking for a macOS application or utility that provides a simple dial pad interface for making cellular phone calls via iPhone Continuity.
My Requirements:

One-Off Calls:
I often need to make one-off calls to new phone numbers and don’t want to create contacts for each number.

Direct Number Input:
A straightforward way to enter a phone number and initiate a call is critical.

Integration with iPhone Continuity:
The app must use macOS's Continuity features (via "Calls on Other Devices") to route calls through my iPhone. (Eg, using a tel://1234567890-like function)

Lightweight:
I’d like something simple and fast... ideally, a small dial pad or menu bar utility that doesn’t require me to interact with FaceTime or Contacts.


What I’ve Tried:

Using tel:// in the Terminal works (open tel://1234567890), but it’s not user-friendly for frequent use.
FaceTime only seems to supports direct dialing for FaceTime Audio calls, not regular cellular calls, and lacks a proper dial pad interface. Ridiculously clunky for regular calls.
Existing apps like SpeedDial focus on contact-based calling, not ad-hoc number entry. Nothing seems to work in an ergonomic fashion.

Must-Have Features:

A dial pad to manually enter phone numbers.
Integration with iPhone Continuity for cellular calls (not FaceTime Audio and not FaceTime Video).
Lightweight design for quick access, such as a menu bar app or small popup window.

Nice-to-Have Features:

Call history for recently dialed numbers.
Keyboard shortcut support for opening the dial pad.

Anyone knows of such a little beastie for macOS that would meet these needs?
